# TypeError: obj is undefined Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I m trying to iterate an array to find if a property matches some condition and retrieve the indexes where the condition applies and thought of using jquerys map method. After finding the exact solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition) and the same problem ,I rolled my coffeescript in order to make things happen.

My object is this :

```
newWaypoint = {waypoint:latlon.toString(), legStart:leg.start_location.toString() ,legNumber:legNo.toString()}
```

and such objects are pushed in a simple array : `@newDraggableWaypoints.push newWaypoint`

This is the code thats giving me headeache:

```
buildNewWaypointsFromDraggable:()->
    item=@allLegWaypoints[0]
    indexes = $.map(@newDraggableWaypoints, (obj, index) =>
        index if obj.legStart  is item
    )
    window.alert indexes.toString()
```

Why is this message presented ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> retrieve the indexes where the condition applies

no, your `map` does retrieve something for *every* element in the array: `index` if the condition is fulfilled and `undefined` else. You will need to use `filter` if you want to exclude some elements. You might do

```
indexes = @newDraggableWaypoints.map (obj, index) =>
  index if obj.legStart is item
.filter (obj) ->
  obj is not undefined
```

or

```
indexes = @newDraggableWaypoints
  .map (obj, index) -> [obj, index]
  .filter ([obj, i]) -> obj.legStart is item
  .map ([o, index]) -> index
```