# What is the correct way to use different `api` with separate query?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have to make 2 queries or more to get data from the server. for example the first i am getting general information like this:

`http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/GetProjectDetails`

on user click i need to show the summary of this project. so i need to pass the `id` to get the data what i requred, the url is :

`http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/GetProjectByID/002`

But how to make seperate query according to the page?

at present i am using a server.js like this:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("tcpApp")
        .factory("server", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

            return $resource('http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/GetProjectDetails');

        }]);

})();

$scope.splash = server.query(); //getting json.
```

It works fine. But how to can update this for both request?

Answer (score 0):

my opinion  don't need to get service call,

because your database values already you had.

if `$scope.splash` have your latest value, then you can get the object by using `indexOf()`.

It's may be no sense. but it is a simple way. else you need call server by **using separate query**

### update:-

- I does not mean **Seperate Query** . I mean you need to pass parameter to the function, if the parameter have any value, then write second query , else you write a first query.
- You can get the data from your `$scope.splash` array by using [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function  [or map() or some()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition) functions

Comment: do you mean that, I need to create separate function for each of my query? actually in the `splash` i am not getting all the values what i need.

Comment: @3gwebtrain , I have update my answer, please checkout that

Comment: Makes sense. can you put me a sample?