# How to splice user correctly from scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to remove user from the list. For some reason, splicing is not removing the user from the list. Can any one help me solve this. I am getting the users from a backend API call, and I am using a PUT method to update it when it removes that particular user.

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.inactive = true;

    $scope.confirmedAction = user => {
        const index = $scope.userInfo.users.indexOf(user);
        $scope.userInfo.users.splice(user, 1);
        $window.location.href = '#/user';
    };

});
```

Comment: where did you defined `user `, is it  `lawyer`?

Comment: its user, i just updated it. sorry, about it

Comment: shouldn't be `.splice(index,1)`?

Comment: @A.Akram I tried that too, still for some reason it does not remove.

Comment: Is index returning a correct value? What are type of `user`? if it's an object `indexOf` won't work !

Comment: @A.Akram yes, its an object

Comment: @A.Akram If the object keeps the same instance, it'll work.

Comment: @Pengyy I already assumed it's not the same instance :) !

Comment: Try changing indexOf into what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @A.Akram can you show an example prior to my code?

Comment: Ok, what is unique in `user` object ? do you have `id` property?

Comment: yes, I do have a id property that is coming from the api call.

Comment: I added an example below, please check if helps!

Comment: @A.Akram I comment under your answer

Answer (score 1):

you should splice based on index

```
$scope.userInfo.users.splice(index, 1);
```

as per the docs [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control)

> index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array

just to show a POC

```
var array = ['val1','val2','val3']
var index = array.indexOf('val2')
array.splice(index,1);

console.log(array);
//['val1','val3']
```

Comment: lets check some steps
1) is it an array
2)is `user` in the array?

Comment: it its an object why not do `delete userInfo.users.user`

Comment: like this delete userInfo.users.splice(index, 1);?

Comment: if yes, that did not removed

Comment: @user3799108 delete won't work with array. it will turn that element to `undefined` but still there. :-)

Comment: sorry i thought the users was an object, delete works if its an object only,wont work for an array

Comment: where is `user` coming from? i have a feeling that `user` is not found in the array

Comment: or, there are duplicate `user` objects in `users`, since indexOf will only return index of first element found, other elements after will not be returned

Comment: the users are coming from my html " ng-repeat="person in userInfo.users | filter:userSearch" >"

Answer (score 0):

From comments I noticed:

`user` is an object, and the function's parameter `user` is not the same instance!

Also assuming you have `id` property in `user` object.

Using [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.inactive = true;
        $scope.confirmedAction = function (user) {
           var index = $scope.userInfo.users.findIndex(u=> u.id == user.id);
          if(index>=0) {
              $scope.userInfo.users.splice(user, 1);
              $window.location.href = '#/user';
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work either. Should I post my PUT method code to see it?

Comment: where did you declared u.id?

Comment: equate both object using angular.equals var index = $scope.userInfo.users.findIndex(u=> angular.equals(u,user));

Comment: @alle I get an error (red scribbly line under => and after the second parenthesis) saying "expecting new line or semicolon" ??

Comment: if you are using e5  var index = $scope.userInfo.users.findIndex(function (u){ return angular.equals(u,user)});