# Dynamic line chart with chart.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js, dynamic-programming

I´m trying to display my data from a MySQL-DB with a `chart.js` line chart. I´m accessing the data from the DB via PHP and receive 1 array with hundreds of strings like this.

The dataset I receive is in the following format:

```
[
{"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"3.02","VALUE2":"3.03","VALUE3":"3.16"},
{"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607932800","VALUE1":"3.72","VALUE2":"2.93","VALUE3":"3.00"},
{"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"3.10","VALUE2":"3.06","VALUE3":"2.98"},
{"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"3.10","VALUE2":"3.06","VALUE3":"2.98"},
{"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"2.30","VALUE2":"2.41","VALUE3":"2.74"},
{"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"2.30","VALUE2":"2.41","VALUE3":"2.74"},
{"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"2.29","VALUE2":"2.37","VALUE3":"2.74"},
{"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"2.29","VALUE2":"2.37","VALUE3":"2.74"},
{"0":"MARKER07","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"2.74","VALUE2":"4.26","VALUE3":"4.26"},
{"0":"MARKER07","timestamp":"1607884400","VALUE1":"2.75","VALUE2":"4.26","VALUE3":"4.26"},
{"0":"MARKER00","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"5.64","VALUE2":"2.09","VALUE3":"1.30"},
{"0":"MARKER00","timestamp":"1607884400","VALUE1":"5.65","VALUE2":"2.09","VALUE3":"1.30"}
]
```

Using javascript, I need to put into the following format so that I can chart each marker-value combination:

```
{
data: {
    m1v1: { 
        [timestamp: 1607932800, value: 1.17],
        ...
    },
    m1v2: {
        [timestamp: 1607932800, value: 3.43],
        ...
    },
    m1v2: {
        [timestamp: 1607932800, value: 2.72],
        ...
    },
    m2v1...and so on
    
}
```

My current code of course only displays one marker because there is nothing dynamic so far. Here is the code I managed so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/chart.php",function(data){ 

    //get the line chart canvas
    var ctx = $("#Chart");

    //line chart data
    var time = [];
    var value1 = [];
    var value2 = [];
    var value3 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var date = new Date( data[i].timestamp *1000);
        time.push(date.toLocaleString());
        value1.push(data[i].VALUE1);
        value2.push(data[i].VALUE2);
        value3.push(data[i].VALUE3);
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: time,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Value1',
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                borderColor: 'blue',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
                radius: 0,
                data: value1
            },
            {
                label: 'Value2',
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                borderColor: 'green',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
                radius: 0,
                data: value2
            },
            {
                label: 'Value2',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                borderColor: 'red',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0,
                radius: 0,
                data: value3
            },
        ]
    };

    //options
    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            text: "Chart",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        labels: {
            fontColor: "#333",
            fontSize: 16
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Value [ ]'
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true   
            }
            }]
        }
    };

    //create Chart class object
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: chartData,
        options: options
    });
});
```

My desired outcome should be something like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Example target format to plot data**

```
{
"data": {
    "m1": {
        "v1": [3.72, 4.03, 5.42],
        "v2": [1.22, 2.31, 3.27],
        "v3": [2.51, 4.04, 1.49],
    },
    "m2": {
        "v1": [1.74, 2.66, 7.56],
        "v2": [3.23, 1.31, 4.45],
        "v3": [1.52, 2.14, 2.32],        
    }
}
```

My SQL database structure:
My "general" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `markerId` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `timestamp`, `sensorID`, `lon`, `lat`) VALUES
(1, '1605087974', 'Marker01', '14.1428918430989', '56.09037310387064'),
(2, '1605087974', 'Marker03', '14.134828135508569', '56.0793705737164'),
(3, '1605087974', 'Marker07', '14.107481648897865', '56.08615752583438'),
(4, '1605087974', 'Marker04', '14.104676881040351', '56.09458825362679'),
(5, '1605087974', 'Marker00', '14.093808405592508', '56.08862523324586');
```

My "value" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `marker01_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE1` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE2` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE3` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `marker01_values` (`id`, `timestamp`, `VALUE1`, `VALUE2`, `VALUE3`) VALUES
(1, '1602838778', '2.18', '2.23', '2.17'),
(2, '1602838800', '2.18', '2.23', '2.17'),
(3, '1602842400', '2.18', '2.24', '2.17'),
(4, '1602846000', '2.18', '2.24', '2.17'),
(5, '1602849600', '2.18', '2.24', '2.17');
```

My PHP to fetch the data:

```
 <?php

$resultArray = array();

// 1. Search in general table for query
$info="WITH ranked_data AS ( SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY markerId ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn FROM data AS m ) SELECT id, markerId, lon, lat FROM ranked_data WHERE rn = 1;";
$sql=($info);

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        // Loop through rows in the result set
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    
            {      
                // Add active row into our temp array
                $tempArray = $row;
                
                $markerId = array_values($tempArray); //saves the value of the table fields 
               
                $sid=$markerId[1]; //saves sensor id value
          
                $tableName=$sid.'_values'; //varaible table name messdata for every iteration
            
                // 2. Next search in value table for query
                $info2="SELECT timestamp, VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 FROM $tableName order by id  desc limit 400";
                $sql2=($info2);

                // Check if there are results
                if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2))
                    {
                        // Loop through rows in the result set
                        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_object())
                            {
                                // Add active row into our temp array
                                $tempArray2 = $row2;
                                
                                // Add all temp arrays to result table
                                $midArray = (object) array_merge((array)$sid, (array) $tempArray2);
                                array_push($resultArray, $midArray);


                            }    
                    }
            }   
    }
}      

// Echo out final result array
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

The structure of the tables should remain the same, because I am not in charge of them...

---

**Edit III 2020/12/29:**

I adjusted my code with the comments posted on 2020/12/29:
I am not quite sure why but I had to set `j = 6`. Otherwise there were duplicates in the output...

```
var obj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) 
{
    var row = Object.values(jsondata[i]);
    var marker = row[0];  
    var index = add(obj, marker);
    
    for (var j = 6; j < row.length; j++) {
        const dateObject = new Date(row[1]*1000);
        var date = dateObject.toLocaleString();
        obj[index].data.push({time: date, value1: row[2], value2: row[3], value3: row[4]}); 
    }
}

console.log(obj);


[![Excel example for chart][3]][3]

I believe, it makes more sense to only display 1 marker with its values at once to keep it clearer. And I hope it is also less complicated code.

The markers (or datasets) that were made with the [answer on 2020/12/29][4] should be able to be chosen with the help of something like a dropdown. But it still needs to be implemented into the chart.js code by a dynamic solution because there will be markers added in the future.
So basically (in my undertanding) there has to be something like a loop to split the JSON data fetch with PHP into the markers (done with answer mentioned above) and something like another loop to add all the data of the markers (split from the PHP) to the chart.js datasets for displaying them as lines. Is this correct? Or is there a more comfortable way to do it?

Regarding the data, there are 3 values (value 1, value 2, value 3) for every timestamp and the next timestamp (approx. every hour) has the next 3 values and so on... The values should be displayed as the come from the database (no average or other calculation in this place).
For this use is it better to split the `PHP` into 3 "datasets" with 1 timestamp each (like: `timestamp1, value1 | timestamp1, value2 | timestamp1, value3`) or just display all values with 1 timestamp (like I did before: `timestamp1, value1, value2, value3`)? Or does something completely else suit better?

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVZkS.png
  [2]: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYCX.png
  [4]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486900/14861343
```

Comment: You may need to convert the numbers to integers instead of strings. Integers will not have double quotes around them. I believe data[i].VALUE1.parseInt() is what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I see what you mean. I treid something similiar with `data.slice` but was not able to slice or parse (with your idea) it dynamically for every new marker... Do you have an idea how to stop after one marker and start over for the next marker?

Comment: Just mallualy pass a small json data string and use console.log to trouble shoot. F12 usually opens the debugger in most browsers. You can even type commands to check the output in the debugger console.

Comment: I'll take a look in an hour or so and see what I can do for you.

Comment: I would also remove the image and just past some lines as code. Easier for members to process/edit.

Comment: Appears split is for a string like the "a,b,c" and will not allow you to access columns json array.

Comment: I updated your question, is the example output of the data format correct?

Comment: Seems like you are creating a lot of work by how you are keeping/pulling the data. If you post more of your code, sql schema, etc, I can help you improve it.

Comment: Also, post your sql schemas and php query. I can help out there, but I'll answer in a separate response here.

Comment: I alreday posted my PHP and SQL for fetching the data from my database within Edit II on 2020/12/21. Or are you looking for other PHP and SQL scripts?

Comment: Ah missed that, I will take a look.

Comment: So the problem here is really the timestamps and the data. Normally the x would have time, but you have multiple values for a series tied to one timestamp. So how are you looking to handle that? average val1-val3? I would recommend putting some data in excel and plot a single sensor out.

Comment: I see... I plot one sensor out with Excel and edit the question.

Comment: So your series is a marker-value combo plottted over time? So ...

```"data": {
    "m1v1": {
        [stamp: 1607884400, val: 2.21],
  [stamp: 1607884411, val: 3.32],
  [stamp: 1607884422, val: 4.53],
  [stamp: 1607884433, val: 3.64],
    },
    "m1v2": {
        [stamp: 1607884400, val: 2.21],
  [stamp: 1607884411, val: 3.32],
  [stamp: 1607884422, val: 4.53],
  [stamp: 1607884433, val: 3.64],
    },
}```?

Comment: I tossed my email in my profile, if you want to reach out I can speed this up for you as this could be drastically simplified for you if I knew some additional details. Just throw StackOverflow and Marker in the subject line.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, multi-level arrays in javascript are more painful because you must do an array-object combo or have a fixed cube:

See https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-push-values-into-this-2D-array-in-JavaScript

Hence why PHP, or even in SQL, it would be easier to build your data set. However, I chose to endure and here you go:

```
 var jsondata = [
 {"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"3.02","VALUE2":"3.03","VALUE3":"3.16"},
 {"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607932800","VALUE1":"3.72","VALUE2":"2.93","VALUE3":"3.00"},
 {"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"3.10","VALUE2":"3.06","VALUE3":"2.98"},
 {"0":"MARKER01","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"3.10","VALUE2":"3.06","VALUE3":"2.98"},
 {"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"2.30","VALUE2":"2.41","VALUE3":"2.74"},
 {"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"2.30","VALUE2":"2.41","VALUE3":"2.74"},
 {"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607943600","VALUE1":"2.29","VALUE2":"2.37","VALUE3":"2.74"},
 {"0":"MARKER03","timestamp":"1607864400","VALUE1":"2.29","VALUE2":"2.37","VALUE3":"2.74"},
 {"0":"MARKER07","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"2.74","VALUE2":"4.26","VALUE3":"4.26"},
 {"0":"MARKER07","timestamp":"1607884400","VALUE1":"2.75","VALUE2":"4.26","VALUE3":"4.26"},
 {"0":"MARKER00","timestamp":"1607882400","VALUE1":"5.64","VALUE2":"2.09","VALUE3":"1.30"},
 {"0":"MARKER00","timestamp":"1607884400","VALUE1":"5.65","VALUE2":"2.09","VALUE3":"1.30"},
 ];

// default obj for testing
var obj = [{
    id : 1, 
    label: 'MARKER01', 
    stamp: '',
    data: [],
}];

for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) 
{
    var row = Object.values(jsondata[i]);
    var marker = row[0];  
    var index = add(obj, marker);
    obj[index].stamp = new Date( row[1] *1000);
    for (var j = 2; j < row.length; j++) {
       obj[index].data.push(row[j]);
    }
   
}

console.log(obj);

/**
 * add function thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition
 */
function add(arr, name) {
  var { length } = arr;
  var id = length + 1;
  var index = arr.findIndex(x => x.label === name);
  if (index === -1) {
    arr.push({ id, label: name, stamp: '', data: []})
    index = arr.findIndex(x => x.label === name);
  } 
  console.log(index);
  return index;
}

// You can test with console.log(add(obj, 'test'));
```

**Ouput**

````
 Object { id: 1, label: "MARKER01", stamp: Sun Dec 13 2020 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), data: Array ["3.02", "3.03", "3.16", "3.72", "2.93", "3.00", "3.10", "3.06", "2.98", "3.10", "3.06", "2.98"] },
 Object { id: 2, label: "MARKER03", stamp: Sun Dec 13 2020 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), data: Array ["2.30", "2.41", "2.74", "2.30", "2.41", "2.74", "2.29", "2.37", "2.74", "2.29", "2.37", "2.74"] },
 Object { id: 3, label: "MARKER07", stamp: Sun Dec 13 2020 13:33:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), data: Array ["2.74", "4.26", "4.26", "2.75", "4.26", "4.26"] },
 Object { id: 4, label: "MARKER00", stamp: Sun Dec 13 2020 13:33:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), data: Array ["5.64", "2.09", "1.30", "5.65", "2.09", "1.30"] }
]```
````

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It feels like, it is really close! Thank you so much for your time! I adjusted it a bit and now I am really able to fetch the data the way I wanted to. But now I am struggling to put the data dynamically into chart.js... I am going to update my question with my adjustments and the problem I am facing.

Comment: Would you mind up voting if that addressed your issue, I work for click's :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Using your code:**

Try parseInt when adding the values to your array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date = new Date( data[i].timestamp *1000);
    time.push(date.toLocaleString());
    value1.push(parseInt(data[i].a));
    value2.push(parseInt(data[i].b));
    console.log(parseInt(data[i].b));
    
}
```

**Debugging**

On the php side, make sure you convert your numbers from string to inter, on the js side you can also do:

```
var jsonString = '[{"x":1.5}, {"x":2.7}]';

var obj  = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log('obj:'); console.log(obj);
// outputs obj array: [{x: 1.5} {x: 2.7}]

var dataset1 = $.map(obj, function(val, i){
    console.log('x: ' + val.x);
    return val.x;
});
console.log('dataset1 :'); console.log(dataset1);
//ouputs new array with just values: (2) [1.5, 2.7]
```

**With Your Full Code**

[image: chartjs]

```
var data = [
{"timestamp":"1607943100","a":"1.5", "b":"2.81", "c":"7.81"},
{"timestamp":"1607943200","a":"2.7", "b":"8.10", "c":"3.10"},
{"timestamp":"1607943300","a":"1.3", "b":"1.77", "c":"4.77"},
{"timestamp":"1607943400","a":"5.2", "b":"4.71", "c":"2.71"},
{"timestamp":"1607943500","a":"9.4", "b":"4.43", "c":"7.43"},
{"timestamp":"1607943600","a":"6.5", "b":"3.26", "c":"9.26"},
];

//get the line chart canvas
var ctx = $("#myChart");

//line chart data
var time = [];
var value1 = [];
var value2 = [];
var value3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date = new Date( data[i].timestamp *1000);
    time.push(date.toLocaleString());
    value1.push(parseInt(data[i].a));
    value2.push(parseInt(data[i].b));
    value3.push(parseInt(data[i].c));
    
    // some debugging
    console.log(parseInt(data[i].b));
}

var chartData = {
    labels: time,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Value1',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderColor: 'blue',
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
            hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 0,
            data: value1
        },
        {
            label: 'Value2',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green',
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
            hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 0,
            data: value2
        },
        {
            label: 'Value3',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
            hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 0,
            data: value3
        },
    ]
};

//options
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        text: "Chart",
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: "#111"
},
legend: {
    display: true,
    position: "top",
    labels: {
        fontColor: "#333",
        fontSize: 16
        }
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Value [ ]'
        },
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true   
        }
        }]
    }
};

//create Chart class object
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: chartData,
    options: options
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I´m going to add the string to int conversion! But I still have a problem with the different markers... I would like to have 1 dataset with MARKER01 displaying lines for VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 in the chart; 1 dataset with MARKER03 displaying lines for VALUE1m VALUE2, VALUE3 in the chart; and so on for all markers dynamically and regardless of the amount of strings per MARKER. Do you have something in mind to solve this aswell?

Comment: Little confused by your request, could you mock up an example, i.e. what does the chart and dataset look like? Also, could you define what marker is vs value 1,2,3?

Comment: Are you asking how to do that on the PHP side?

Comment: I updated my original question. I hope it is more clear know, what I am trying to do. I would like to keep it all in JavaScript and leave the PHP as it is if possible. Thank you for your patience so far!

Comment: So MARKER01 would have three series, one for each  [val1,val1, ...],  [val2,val2, ...], [val3,val3, ...]? Each series would have a different number of values? if so that is easy, but I would tell you to post your SQL and php, its way easier on that end.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting date and time:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script>
var s1 = {
  label: 's1',
  borderColor: 'blue',
  data: [
    { x: 1606943100000, y: 1.5 },
    { x: 1607943200000, y: 2.7 },
    { x: 1608943300000, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 1609943400000, y: 5.2 },
    { x: 1610943500000, y: 9.4 },
    { x: 1611943600000, y: 6.5 },
  ]
};

var s2 = {
  label: 's2',
  borderColor: 'red',
  data: [
    { x: 1604953100000, y: 4.5 },
    { x: 1607963200000, y: 2.7 },
    { x: 1608973300000, y: 3.3 },
    { x: 1613983400000, y: 4.2 },
    { x: 1620993500000, y: 7.4 },
    { x: 1632043600000, y: 6.5 },
  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: { datasets: [s1, s2] },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unitStepSize: 500,
          unit: 'hour', // check displayFormat to match
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'hA', 
            day: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            month: 'YYYY-MM'
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```